# GEO Place Manipulation

Tags: twitter, geocoding

I have encountered a very unusual  and bizarre situation in Twitter. A user with account @hh88hhhh seems to tweet from multiple locations  even though it's nearly impossible he/she can be in these far apart locations! Can location be directly manipulated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [add a location to a tweet](https://support.twitter.com/articles/122236), you have to option of picking the location from a searchable list of various nearby locations. The search here isn't limited in any way, so you can practically choose any location you wish.

Comment: That would defeat the purpose and the locations fluctuate between different continents!

Comment: @Khal Be as it may, this is how the feature currently works.